# Nodejs connect to Redshift using temporal credentials error

Tags: node.js, amazon-redshift

I'd like to connect to Redshift using temporal credentials.

I'd tried connecting with master username and password and it works fine. The problem of the temporal credentials is the username that is following format:

```
username: 'IAM:awsuser'.
```

So I think the connection is not understanding correctly the ":". So it always through invalid password. I have try this username and password from the Redshift query-editor and it connects without any problem.

This is the configuration I'm using:

```
const configRed = {
  host: 'redshift-cluster-name.aaaaaaa.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
  user: 'IAM:awsuser',
  password: data.DbPassword,
  database: 'dev',
  port: 5439,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
  max: 10000
};

redshiftPool = new psql.Pool(configRed);

redshiftCon = await redshiftPool.connect();
```

I have also tried using the username with encodeURIComponent:

```
    user: encodeURIComponent('IAM:awsuser'),
```

It through next error:

```
  "errorMessage": "password authentication failed for user \"IAM:awsuser\"",
```

Could be possible to change the connection URL in the PG library, for some custom URL like:

```
jdbc:redshift:iam://examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev
```

Comment: Could it be that the "IAM" part is taken as password?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Could be, but the error give the correct user.. "IAM:awsuser". Maybe is it possible to change the connection URL in the PG library?

Comment: About the custom URL, "jdbc" is a java driver for database connections.  How could Node.js make use of that?

Comment: Maybe there is another Node.js library that could uses custom URLs for that.. Not sure. @GerardH.Pille

Comment: I'm trying to just connect to redshift through node using the aws-sdk/client-redshift-data package but I seemingly can't connect at all, I just want to query the db and get some data back, any pointers? @AsierGomez

Comment: I used PG library, check if you have correct permissions in the Redshift security group. If yes, maybe happens something like my case. Check that library doc for how to make the connection.

Comment: @AsierGomez yeah used node-posgres and it worked fine thanks for that. For some reason I couldn't get the redshift dataclient to connect in node. No idea just connection timing out. This solution works tho, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying "ssl: true" in the params argument when creating the Pool object indeed works:

```
const configRed = {
  host: 'redshift-cluster-name.aaaaaaa.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
  user: 'IAM:awsuser',
  password: data.DbPassword,
  database: 'dev',
  port: 5439,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
  max: 10000,
  ssl: true
};
```